# Write date of last commit to a branch to a text file

Tags: svn

In SVN, I would like to get the date of the last commit to each of the branches in our repository and output the results to a text file. My goal is to then take this list and clean up or reach out to the owners of branches that haven't been committed to in roughly 2 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I chose.

```
svn ls https://branches.ios.com/svn/directory/Main/Branches --xml > C:\OutputDirectory\svnbranches.xml
```

I output the branch list to an xml file and parsed it to find the last commit date for each of the branches. In the xml file it looks something like this:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lists>
<list
   path="https://branches.ios.com/svn/directory/Main/Branches">
<entry
   kind="dir">
<name>NameOfBranch</name>
<commit
   revision="10010">
<author>CommitAuthor</author>
<date>2000-01-01T01:01:01.824524Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
</list>
</lists>
```

Searching for the date XML element should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
for b in `svn ls path/to/branches`; do
  echo "$b: `s info path/to/branches/$b | grep '^Last Changed Date:' | sed 's/^Last Changed Date: //g'`";
done
```

This will only work if there are no spaces in your branch names, though.